# Is it possible to use an environment variable instead of a "linked resource"?

Tags: eclipse, flexbuilder

Our project files have an absolute path and I am trying to replace instances of these with Linked Resources in order to make the dev environment portable between different workstations.

Our Windows workstations already have a number of useful environment variables set to determine the location of various resources needed to build parts of the project.

Now I'm finding that from Flex Builder (i.e. Eclipse) it is not possible to use these environment variables, but that each user will have to go into the Workspace>General settings and set up "Linked Resources", which are for all intents and purposes exactly the same thing as environment variables, but for Eclipse.  This is an extra, repetitive step consider this information is already available on the workstations.  Is there no way to tell Eclipse to use an environment variable instead of a Linked Resource, or to make a Linked Resources which references an environment variable?

I am thinking the only convenient solution may be a batch file to create the Linked Resource automatically, but this seems kludgy and error-prone to me.

Comment: Use version control, and check in all your projects and then have each developer create their own workspace and checkout all projects from the repo? I would suggest against linked folders/resources as part of a development environment setup.

Comment: I don't understand, that's what we do.  Each developer has a workspace and imports the projects, which are checked out of version control.  However some of the project files require paths to files on the dev computers, and these are currently in the project files that are in source control.  I am trying to replace these references in the project files to links relative to where certain resources are installed, which are available as environment variables.

Comment: Okay, now I understand your dillema. Are all your required file paths that are absolute in a single properties file or are they in multiple properties/java files?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can use the `${ENV-name}` token in the Eclipse *Linked Resources* sheet in the project properties dialog.  For instance, if you specify `${ENV-TEMP}` it will resolve to the value of the environment variable `TEMP`.

(Oddly, I could not find an explanation of the `${ENV}` syntax anywhere on the web, but I just guessed that it might use `${ENV-name}` syntax, similar to how `${project_loc}/..` is converted to `PARENT-1-project_loc`...)

Comment: Hmmm... this didn't work for me. I wonder what version it might have worked on.

Comment: For me this didn't work as well... What version did you use Colin?

Comment: I think I was using Eclipse v4.2.0 in a development package supplied by Freescale.  Perhaps the feature was removed since then or maybe it was a nonstandard feature added by Freescale in their CodeWarrior distribution.